# IE 11 ХmlHttpRequest onreadystatechange and compatibility

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-11

We use in project ajax with callback function. 
In IE version before 11 everithing works fine.
Also we use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Looks like in IE 11 script.onreadystatechange and script.readyState replated with script.onload (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Now in IE11 handleState doesn't call. And page is freezing. 
Tried to change onreadystatechange to onload and xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); to xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); but it doesn't help. I guess it doesn't help because we use compatible mode

I can't delete < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />, because there are many functionality of this page that will be broken without this code.

```
function callServer (request, xml, callback, callbackArgs) {
    try {
        //IE browser
    xh= new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }
    catch (e) {
        //Firefox or Safari
        xh=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    try {
        xh.open("POST", request, true);

        xh.onreadystatechange  = function() { handleState(callback,callbackArgs); }; 
        xh.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        xh.send(xml);
    } catch(e) {}
```

}

```
function handleState(callback, callbackArgs) {  
    if (xh.readyState == 4) {
        // call callback
    }
}
```

Any ideas for quick fix ?

Comment: What browsers are you supporting? Do you really need to support IE5.5?

Comment: No, we don't need to support IE 5.5. We support Internet Explorer 6 SP1 and above

Comment: Why do you use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />`? That's generally a pretty horrible idea unless you have a really good reason..

Comment: It is expensive to change a lot of functionality for every IE version :(

Comment: You write standards complaint code _once_ and you're golden. What  breaks when you remove that header (or set it to Edge)?

Comment: For deleting this we need to rewrite all page. Page looks broken whan I delete this <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43883/discussion-between-victoria-and-benjamin-gruenbaum)

Comment: [IE11 doesn't support document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx#docmode), so you can't make it work without rewriting the code according to the standards. I guess your tech lead won't receive his bonus this year.